# How to change value of com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.TransactionManagerService TransactionTimeout at the run-time?

Tags: jboss, transactions, jmx, jta

We have JBoss [EAP] 4.3.0.GA_CP01 environment and I need to modify the

```
TransactionTimeout
```

property of

```
com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.TransactionManagerService
```

but whenever i try to change the value via MBean from JMX-Console; following stacktrace shows up:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot set transaction timeout once MBean has started
com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.TransactionManagerService.setTransactionTimeout(TransactionManagerService.java:323)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AttributeDispatcher.invoke(AttributeDispatcher.java:136)
org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanAttributeInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanAttributeInterceptor.java:103)
org.jboss.mx.interceptor.PersistenceInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceInterceptor.java:76)
org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.setAttribute(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:461)
org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.setAttribute(MBeanServerImpl.java:608)
org.jboss.jmx.adaptor.control.Server.setAttributes(Server.java:206)
org.jboss.jmx.adaptor.html.HtmlAdaptorServlet.updateAttributes(HtmlAdaptorServlet.java:236)
org.jboss.jmx.adaptor.html.HtmlAdaptorServlet.processRequest(HtmlAdaptorServlet.java:98)
org.jboss.jmx.adaptor.html.HtmlAdaptorServlet.doPost(HtmlAdaptorServlet.java:82)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
```

Is there a way programmatically to change the value of TransactionTimeout without bouncing the server at the run-time??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Nicholas!

Here is the Java code which can be used to change the transaction timeout on runtime...

```
MBeanServer mBeanServer = MBeanServerLocator.locateJBoss();
TransactionManagerDelegate tmd = (TransactionManagerDelegate) mBeanServer.getAttribute(new ObjectName("jboss:service=TransactionManager"), "TransactionManager");
System.out.println("Prev: " + tmd.getTransactionTimeout());
tmd.setTransactionTimeout(200);
System.out.println("New: " + tmd.getTransactionTimeout());
```

And as you quoted, 
**Note that this will not change the value reported in the MBean's TransactionTimeout attribute** however the value will be effective for all transactions post this operation.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a groovy example of how to do this (using embedded groovy inside a JBoss 4.3.0.GA_CP01 instance):

```
mbeanserver.getAttribute(JMXHelper.objectName("jboss:service=TransactionManager"), "TransactionManager").setTransactionTimeout(200);
```

Basically, the MBeanService `com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.TransactionManagerService` does not allow you to change the default transaction timeout, but if you retrieve the attribute **TransactionManager** (an instance of **com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.TransactionManagerDelegate**), it exposes the method:

```
public void com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.setTransactionTimeout(int) throws javax.transaction.SystemException
```

Note that this will not change the value reported in the MBean's **TransactionTimeout** attribute, but all transactions started after this method is called will have the new transaction timeout.

More groovy code:

```
def txManager = mbeanserver.getAttribute(JMXHelper.objectName("jboss:service=TransactionManager"), "TransactionManager");
TX.exec({
    println "Timeout:${txManager.getTransactionTimeout()}";
});
txManager.setTransactionTimeout(txManager.getTransactionTimeout() * 2);
TX.exec({
    println "Timeout:${txManager.getTransactionTimeout()}";
});
```

Output:

> Timeout:200
>   Timeout:400

Comment: Thank you.... let me see how I can use this in my environment. I don't use Groovy.

Comment: Yeah... I find groovy useful for examples because I can test it quickly and it's intent is usually clear as pseudo code.