# How to change value of com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.TransactionManagerService TransactionTimeout at the run-time? continued

Tags: jboss, transactions, jmx, jta

I asked this question earlier [How to change value of com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.TransactionManagerService TransactionTimeout at the run-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390873/how-to-change-value-of-com-arjuna-ats-jbossatx-jta-transactionmanagerservice-tra)

As per the answer provided I found this java code to do my job:

```
MBeanServer mBeanServer = MBeanServerLocator.locateJBoss();
TransactionManagerDelegate tmd = (TransactionManagerDelegate) mBeanServer.getAttribute(new ObjectName("jboss:service=TransactionManager"), "TransactionManager");
System.out.println("Prev: " + tmd.getTransactionTimeout());
tmd.setTransactionTimeout(200);
System.out.println("New: " + tmd.getTransactionTimeout());
```

Now here is the problem... the code executes fine but when i check from JMX-console the Transaction Timeout is still the same.

When i debug i found that TM instance fetched from mBeanServer and TM instance available on jmx-console are different!

Is there any way to update the TM instance which is available on JMX-Console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above works and does change the transaction timeout. As @Nicholas mentioned
**They are different object instances, but there is only one transaction manager.**

however 
**The value reported in the MBean's TransactionTimeout attribute doesn't change**

and this caused me to ask this question on the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Bharat;

They are different object instances, but there is only one transaction manager. What you're seeing is simply two different wrappers/proxies for the internal Arjuna transaction manager core. This code acquires the current transaction from the two different proxies, but the actual transaction UUID is the same:

```
def txManager = mbeanserver.getAttribute(JMXHelper.objectName("jboss:service=TransactionManager"), "TransactionManager");
TX.exec({
    println txManager.getTransaction();
    println mbeanserver.getAttribute(JMXHelper.objectName("jboss:service=TransactionManager"), "UserTransaction");
    assert mbeanserver.getAttribute(JMXHelper.objectName("jboss:service=TransactionManager"), "UserTransaction").toString().replace("Transaction: ", "").equals(txManager.getTransaction().toString())
    println "Timeout:${txManager.getTransactionTimeout()}";
});
txManager.setTransactionTimeout(200);
TX.exec({
    println txManager.getTransaction();
    println mbeanserver.getAttribute(JMXHelper.objectName("jboss:service=TransactionManager"), "UserTransaction");
    assert mbeanserver.getAttribute(JMXHelper.objectName("jboss:service=TransactionManager"), "UserTransaction").toString().replace("Transaction: ", "").equals(txManager.getTransaction().toString())
    println "Timeout:${txManager.getTransactionTimeout()}";
});
```

Output:

> TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: ae60d43:d590:4ffc7013:265841
>   status: ActionStatus.RUNNING > 
>   Transaction: TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: ae60d43:d590:4ffc7013:265841 status:ActionStatus.RUNNING > Timeout:200 TransactionImple < ac,
>   BasicAction: ae60d43:d590:4ffc7013:265842 status: ActionStatus.RUNNING
>   > Transaction: TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction:
>   ae60d43:d590:4ffc7013:265842 status: ActionStatus.RUNNING >
>   Timeout:400

Comment: Thank you @Nicholas !!! Eventually I was able to figure out the same. Your solution has worked for me.